# How to write a python Script to fill and submit google form (example link in description) automatically in a loop say 100 times

Tags: python, forms

I have to submit the google form with checkboxes and radio buttons by filling random options. How to write python script to do it in a loop for 100 times. (100 times fill and submit 100 times)

google form like this (https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScqkoxkYN6BTF00gab9in7ih9fso96IC-9VpcRNa0KpnHlEyg/viewform)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing would be to use [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/). Generally it's used for automated browser testing so it would probably be perfect for filling out a form.

Another option would be to use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/) commands to make GET requests to wherever the form is being sent, if you have access to how the api works and the values it's expecting.